# Проблемы с доступом к файлу из приложения Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть файл базы данных SQLite, необходимо его скопировать на SD карту смартфона Android. Написал класс для копирования файла с места его хранения приложением в папку на SD карте. В манифесте Android разрешил доступ по чтению и записи: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Но при попытке копирования возникает ошибка: отказано в доступе. Подскажите, что ещё нужно настроить, чтобы получить доступ к SD карте. В выложенном коде попытка скопировать в ExternalStorage и затем на SD карту. В обоих случаях идет отказ в доступе.

```
    using System.IO;
    using BreadDiary.Droid;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(DBCopyService))]
    namespace BreadDiary.Droid
    {
        public class DBCopyService : IDBCopy
        {
            public DBCopyService()
            {

            }

            public void DBCopy()
            {
                // Копируем файл базы данных в доступное место на SD-карту
                var safePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "BreadDiary.db3");
                var path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, "BreadDiary.db3");
                if (File.Exists(safePath))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(safePath);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(path);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState);
                    if (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState == "mounted")
                    {
// Запись в ExternalStorage                        
File.Copy(safePath, path, true);
// Запись на SD карту
File.Copy(safePath, "/storage/sdcard0/Download/BreadDiary.db3", true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем все было просто. Необходимо было подключить плагин Plugin.Permissions и при первом обращении запросить права доступа во время исполнения приложения.

Второй нюанс заключается в том, что база данных SQLite на мобильном устройстве Android хранится не в одном файле, а в трех, при этом в файле *.db3 хранится только заголовок, а данные хранятся в файлах *.db3_shm и *db3_wal. Т. е. необходимо скопировать три файла.